# Calculate the number of moves requires for a knight chess piece

Tags: c, pathfinding

It's possible to work out the number of moves required to move from (0, 0) to (A, B) for a knight on an infinite chess board in O(1) time.

This is an attempt at a solution to do it in O(n) time, where n is the number of moves required.

```
#define ABS(a) ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); _a > 0 ? _a : -_a; })

int movesRequired(int A, int B) {
    int X = 0, Y = 0;
    int count = 0;
    if (!(((A-X) % 2) ^ ((Y-B) % 2)))
        return -1;
    while (X != A && Y != B) {
        int distX = A-X;
        int distY = B-Y;
        if (ABS(distX) > ABS(distY)) {
            X += distX>0?2:-2;
            Y += distY>0?1:-1;
        } else {
            X += distX>0?1:-1;
            Y += distY>0?2:-2;
        }
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

It returns the minimum moves required, or -1 if it's not possible.

What I'm interested in:

- As far as I am aware, this runs in O(n) time. However, I may not be correct. Does it?
- Is there a way to improve my algorithm so it runs in O(n) time?

Comment: We are only considering one knight on this infinite chessboard, right?  That's what I'm assuming since collisions with other chess pieces wouldn't be legal.

Comment: @syb0rg Yes, just the knight.

Comment: Under what conditions is it not possible for a Knight to access a square?

Comment: "It's possible to work out the number of moves required to move from (0, 0) to (A, B) for a knight on an infinite chess board in O(1) time." This statement is *false*. The proof is very simple: the output is **not** constant in size. If you choose bigger and bigger `A` and `B` in the infinite chessboard the number of moves increases and thus the size of the output. The time to compute such number of moves `n` is **at least** O(log(n)) otherwise the algorithm wouldn't even have the time to produce output.

Comment: A knight can always move to any square, it's never impossible because no square is unreachable to a knight: see for example [Knight's tour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knight's_tour).

Answer (score 18):

### \$O(1)\$ Discussion

> Is it possible to calculate the distance in \$O(1)\$ time complexity?

Yes, it is.

This problem is called the *"Knight's distance"* problem, and googling it find a number of references.

This problem was posed as part of the South African "Computer Olympiad" in 2007 for high-school students to solve.... (I know, kids these days.... :) ). The specification was such that some input values for the programs were large enough that \$O(n)\$ solutions would fail to compute in the required time limits, so to get full marks you needed to (devise, and) compute the \$O(1)\$ system.

The [problem description](http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/old/saco2007/day1_2007.pdf), and enough of the description of [the \$O(1)\$ solution are](http://olympiad.cs.uct.ac.za/old/saco2007/day1_2007_solutions.pdf) available. In case the .za net goes dead, here's the description of the solution:

> **4 The Knights Who Say Ni**
>
> The (x, y)-coordinates in the 50% constraints are small enough to
>   generate a full grid of the minimum number of moves required to get
>   from any point to (0,0). The grid can be generated by a breadth-first
>   search (BFS).
>
> We know that getting to (0,0) requires 0 moves. We therefore know that
>   the points (1,2), (2,1) and the other six movements each require 1
>   move. From each of those points with a shortest distance of 1, we can
>   take another step in each direction for a shortest path of 2. However,
>   some moves will bring us back to a point we have already found a
>   shorter distance for and we therefore discard such moves. We continue
>   this until the grid is full and then use the grid to find the
>   distances for each knight.
>
> To get 100%, a lot of scribbling on paper is required to make some key
>   observations and work out some formulae. The first thing to note is
>   that the grid is symetrical along the x, y axis and the lines `y = ±x`.
>   You can therefore convert all points `(x, y)` into an equivalent
>   point such that the new `0 ≤ y ≤ x`.
>
> The magic formula is:
>
> $$
> f(x, y) = \left\{
>  \begin{array}{ll}
>   2 \left\lfloor \frac{y - \delta}{3} \right\rfloor  + \delta & \mbox{if } y > \delta \\
>   \delta - 2 \left\lfloor \frac{\delta - y}{4} \right\rfloor & \mbox{otherwise}
>  \end{array}
> \right.
> $$
>
> where \$δ = x − y\$.

### Are there mistakes

Yes.... All squares are accessible to the knight. Why do you have a restriction?

I put your code in to an Ideone that loops through the 100 targets in positions (0,0) through (9,9).... and [its results are disappointing](http://ideone.com/Akyx2M)... Does your code work?

NO. it does not. It produces wildly wrong values.....

Now, the algorithm I referenced above does not seem to be producing good values either (at least a short range....), but seriously? Your code hardly works at all :(

Lots, and lots of -1 distances, and lots and lots of 0.....

Comment: Found a solution with O(1) time. https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Knight-Distance

Comment: For x=1, and y=0 the formula gives 1, how is this possible?

Comment: The formulae seemingly works only for larger input, when there is no back-motion necessary. However, I'm still wondering how did they figure it out.

Comment: This formula has a small mistake, for correct one look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/41704071/827753

Answer (score 14):

A few notes (with efficiency aside, as you said):

- Your defined `ABS` surrounded by parenthesis is [not the usual way that C programmers declare macros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154136/1937270) so that they aren't problematic.

  ```
  #define ABS(a) do { typeof (a) _a = (a); _a > 0 ? _a : -_a; } while(0)
  ```

  Also, there is no point of using `typeof` in this instance.  Just use the `abs()` function from `<math.h>`, or define a more simple ABS macro.

  ```
  #define ABS(x) ((x) > 0 ? x : -x)
  ```

  Note that you will have to use the `fabs()` for finding the absolute value of floating point numbers using the `<math.h>` library.
- Why are all of your single letter variable names capitalized?
- You need to let some of your code breathe a bit to make it easier to read (in my opinion).

  ```
  X += distX > 0 ? 2 : -2;
  ```
- Use more comments to say what your code does and why. Don't overdo this though.

  ```
  if (!(((A-X) % 2) ^ ((Y-B) % 2)))  //<insert description here>
  ```

Comment: On that last point, the operands and operators should be separated for readability.

Comment: Thanks for your answer syb0rg. I agree with the first and last suggestions. Using capitalised names was solely because the specification had `A` and `B` capitalised.

Comment: @Alec That's fine.  It's just more common for variable names to start with a lowercase letter, so I was wondering why it was uppercase.

Comment: I prefer comments on the previous line, not inline.

Comment: @ChrisW Depending on how long the comments are, yes.  If it is a short description that can easily fit on the same line, then I usually put them on the same line.

Answer (score 9):

I have a bit of a bone to pick with this:

```
#define ABS(a) ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); _a > 0 ? _a : -_a; })
```

Firstly, `typeof` is a gcc extension, so by using this, you're making your code less portable. To be fair, for something small like this, it's not a big problem, but it's a bit of a bad habit to get into. In this case, it's also not even needed.

```
#define ABS(x) ((x) > 0 ? x : -x)
```

works just as well.

However, all of this isn't really necessary. `<math.h>` defines `abs` (for integers) and `fabs` (for floating point values) for you. Use the standard library unless you have very good reason not to.

Comment: On the other hand, if you _are_ using a compiler that supports `typeof`, such as GCC or Clang, this `ABS(x)` macro avoid evaluating its argument twice.